# JavaScriptでキャッシュされたファイルのリストを取得する

Tags: javascript

タイトルの通り、JavaScriptでキャッシュされたファイルのリストを取得することは可能でしょうか？もし可能ならば、詳細を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

具体的にはブラウザにWebフォントがキャッシュされているかどうかを調べ、キャッシュされていればすぐにページを表示し、されていない場合はローディング画面を出してからページを表示させたいと思っています。

Comment: 主語が無いので質問として解読しづらいものとなっています。何がどこでキャッシュしたファイルなのか？調査する主体は何で、得た結果をどう使いたいのかとか、質問を編集する形で追記してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

キャッシュファイルというのはブラウザのキャッシュファイルを指しているのでしょうか？
そうであれば、File API を利用して取得できなくもないですけど、ブラウザによって保存場所が異なるのでいずれにしろ難しいのではないかと思います。